# How do I stop transitions when my website initially loads?

Tags: html, css

When my website loads, the elements of this class are transitioned to their starting positions.

Is there a way for me to have a smooth movement when hovering over an element and to stop hovering without having the initial transitions play out?

```
.header_subpages {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20p;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    transition: 1s;
}

.header_subpages:hover {
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Your title together with the post itself doesn't make any sense. What is the actual question?

Comment: One obvious issue is `p` isn't a unit of measurement in CSS so `font-size: 20p;` should be `font-size: 20px;`

Comment: using this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/eywho23f/) your code doesn't do that, so there is something else affecting it.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]